# how to integrate geomajas i.e. clientside gwt base framework and serverside

Tags: java, geomajas

I am new to geomajas opensourse project.I have successfully build client-GWT maven project and server-side maven project.Now i want to integrate client side with server side project so that i can use server side geomajas as back end for client-GWT .I am not getting specific documents or commands to integrate client-side and server side. So anyone having knowledge of geomajas integration please provide me specific steps or commands ,so that i can successfully integrate client side and server side geomajas.